# Pyspark to iterate through year, month and date folders and subfolders to get the latest file

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake

Could someone please help with some code in pyspark to loop over folders and subfolders to get the latest file.

The folder and subfolders are like below. Now I want to loop over to the latest year folder, and then latest month folder and then latest date folder to get the file.

```
Raw/2019
Raw/2020/06/21
Raw/2021/03/18/file.csv
Raw/2021/04/13/file.csv
Raw/2021/04/14/file.csv
```

Comment: why do you need pyspark for that? Are the files stored in hdfs?

Comment: @pythonic833 This is an incremental data. The data will be loaded daily into the datalake storage. So I need to pull the latest file from the storage. And then I will be mounting that data.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't need Spark to do that. Since you're using Azure Databricks, you should use [Databricks File System API](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html) instead, so something like this

```py
lst = dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs:/Raw/")
print(sorted(lst, reverse=True)[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get the latest directory would be the File System API pltc mentioned

To add further , I have a small utility function that iterates the input path recursively leveraging the File System API and sorts them using `getctime` -

```
def latest_dir(inp):
  
  def recur_directory(inp,res=[]):
      inp_dir = dbutils.fs.ls(inp)
      for dr in inp_dir:
          if os.path.isdir("/dbfs" + dr.path[5:]):
              d = recur_directory(dr.path,res)
          else:
            res += [inp]
            break
              
      return res
  
  dir_lst = [ recur_directory(x.path) for x in dbutils.fs.ls(inp[5:]) ][0]
  
  return sorted(["/dbfs" + x[5:] for x in dir_lst], key=os.path.getctime,reverse=True)
```